# Calculating the distances between all point (xy) on a plot with macros (VBA) in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a method of doing this that involves R programming language, but Im looking to do this purely in excel instead to save time and make it more user friendly.

Basically, I need to calculate the distance between all combinations of points (x,y) coordinates for histological analysis.The data collected is in the form X and Y columns. There may only be two or three points, there could be as many as 100.  Imagining a data set consists of points (x,y) 1,2,3 and 4. I would need to calculate distances 1 to 2, 1 to 3, 1 to 4, 2 to 3, 2 to 4 and 3 to 4.

Ideally, I would have a macro that prompts you to select the X column, then the y column, click ok, then copies the resulting distances to the clipboard or to a new workbook.

Any thoughts on this or refer me to pre-existing forums that may be similar to this?

Mostly, I lack the knowledge of how combinations work in VBA and how to keep the x and y for any given point together.

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your case and corresponding sample data:

```
X   Y
2   4
4   1
3   2
2   3
```

you can try the following VBA code snippet

```
Sub CalculateAllDistances()
Dim X1 As Double
Dim Y1 As Double
Dim X2 As Double
Dim Y2 As Double

Dim Distance As Double
For i = 2 To 4
    X1 = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Y1 = Cells(i, 2).Value
    For j = i + 1 To 5
        X2 = Cells(j, 1).Value
        Y2 = Cells(j, 2).Value
        'Calculate Distance between Cell1 (X1,Y1) and Cell2(X2,Y2)
        Distance = Sqr((Y2 - Y1) ^ 2 + (X2 - X1) ^ 2)
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome: better late than never :-). I am glad it works for you. Please mark the answer accepted if it satisfies your request. Best regards,